# Convert CST to UTC at the time of the Daylight Savings start and end in Oracle Sql

Tags: oracle, datetime

I am trying to convert a timestamp from localtimezone (America/Chicago, i.e. CST) to UTC in Oracle SQL. I tried few SQL statements:

> SELECT CAST('08-MAR-2020 02.05.02.575000000 AM' AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM dual;

> SELECT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CAST('08-MAR-2020 02.05.02.575000000 AM' AS TIMESTAMP)) FROM dual;

> select from_tz(CAST ('08-MAR-2020 02.05.02.575000000 AM' AS TIMESTAMP),'CST') at  TIME ZONE 'UTC' with_daylight_savings from dual;

> SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('08-MAR-15 02.05.02.575000000 AM') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM dual;

However, I get the same error message with all these statements.

**ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval.**

**01878. 00000 -  "specified field not found in datetime or interval"**

***Cause:    The specified field was not found in the datetime or interval.**

***Action:   Make sure that the specified field is in the datetime or interval.**

It converts all other times just fine, except the time of Daylight Savings starts and end in between 2 to 3 AM. If I change to 01:00 AM or 03:00 AM it converts the timestamp just fine.

I tried couple of solutions, but none seem to work for me.

FirstI tried to add the TZD element with TZR element.

> SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('08-MAR-2020 02.05.02.575000000 America/Chicago CDT', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SS.FF9 TZR TZD', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM dual;

However, running this statement, it gives me **ORA-01857: not a valid time zone**. If I run the same statement with CST, I get **ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval.**

My ask is this. I have table in oracle which has a field with TIMESTAMP (without TIMEZONE information) like this: **'08-MAR-2020 02.05.02.575000000 AM'**. I am considering that the timezone to be **'America/Chicago'**. My goal is to get the string as an output in this format **'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF"Z"'** converted to UTC time.

Please share if anyone bumped into it and was able to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: Hi . Are you getting the error in all the queries ? I mean, I only have a problem with the third one, and I think I know why. But the others work ok for me. Can you reproduce the error in your sqlplus ?

Comment: Others work for you because you SYSTEMTIMESTAMP may be the one that has no ambiguity. Just like the answer says, CST has different TZ_OFFSET. That is why they present error for me, biutot for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'08-MAR-2020 02.05.02.575000000 AM'` is not a `TIMESTAMP` value, it is a **string**.

When you like to convert a string into a TIMESTAMP then you should always include the format:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('08-MAR-2020 02.05.02.575000000 AM', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SS.FF9', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american')
```

If you like to create a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` then you should use

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('08-MAR-2020 02.05.02.575000000 AM ???', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SS.FF9 TZR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american')
```

I don't know what `CST` means, it is ambiguous:

```
SELECT tzabbrev, tzname, TZ_OFFSET(tzname) 
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES tz 
where tzabbrev = 'CST'

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|TZABBREV                       |TZNAME                        |TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME)|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|CST                            |America/Atikokan              |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/Bahia_Banderas        |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/Belize                |-06:00           |
|CST                            |America/Cambridge_Bay         |-06:00           |
|CST                            |America/Cancun                |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/Chicago               |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/Chihuahua             |-06:00           |
|CST                            |America/Coral_Harbour         |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/Costa_Rica            |-06:00           |
|CST                            |America/Detroit               |-04:00           |
|CST                            |America/El_Salvador           |-06:00           |
|CST                            |America/Fort_Wayne            |-04:00           |
|CST                            |America/Guatemala             |-06:00           |
|CST                            |America/Havana                |-04:00           |
|CST                            |America/Hermosillo            |-07:00           |
|CST                            |America/Indiana/Indianapolis  |-04:00           |
|CST                            |America/Indiana/Knox          |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/Indiana/Marengo       |-04:00           |
|CST                            |America/Indiana/Petersburg    |-04:00           |
|CST                            |America/Indiana/Tell_City     |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/Indiana/Vevay         |-04:00           |
|CST                            |America/Indiana/Vincennes     |-04:00           |
|CST                            |America/Indiana/Winamac       |-04:00           |
|CST                            |America/Indianapolis          |-04:00           |
|CST                            |America/Iqaluit               |-04:00           |
|CST                            |America/Kentucky/Louisville   |-04:00           |
|CST                            |America/Kentucky/Monticello   |-04:00           |
|CST                            |America/Knox_IN               |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/Louisville            |-04:00           |
|CST                            |America/Managua               |-06:00           |
|CST                            |America/Matamoros             |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/Mazatlan              |-06:00           |
|CST                            |America/Menominee             |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/Merida                |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/Mexico_City           |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/Monterrey             |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/North_Dakota/Beulah   |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/North_Dakota/Center   |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/North_Dakota/New_Salem|-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/Ojinaga               |-06:00           |
|CST                            |America/Pangnirtung           |-04:00           |
|CST                            |America/Rainy_River           |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/Rankin_Inlet          |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/Regina                |-06:00           |
|CST                            |America/Resolute              |-05:00           |
|CST                            |America/Swift_Current         |-06:00           |
|CST                            |America/Tegucigalpa           |-06:00           |
|CST                            |America/Thunder_Bay           |-04:00           |
|CST                            |America/Winnipeg              |-05:00           |
|CST                            |Asia/Chongqing                |+08:00           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Once you have a you can convert to UTC:

```
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('08-MAR-2020 02.05.02.575000000 AM ???', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SS.FF9 TZR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american'))
```

or

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('08-MAR-2020 02.05.02.575000000 AM ???', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH.MI.SS.FF9 TZR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') AT TIME ZONE UTC
```

If the time is ambiguous, i.e. transition of Daylight Savings then you can specify it also (using TIMESTAMP literal as it is shorter):

```
TIMESTAMP '2020-03-08 02.05.02.575 America/Los_Angeles PDT'
```

See [TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE Data Type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#i1006081)

> To eliminate the ambiguity of boundary cases when the time switches
> from Standard Time to Daylight Saving Time, use both the TZR format
> element and the corresponding TZD format element. The TZD format
> element is an abbreviation of the time zone region with Daylight
> Saving Time information included. Examples are PST for U. S. Pacific
> Standard Time and PDT for U. S. Pacific Daylight Time. The following
> specification ensures that a Daylight Saving Time value is returned:
>
> ```
> TIMESTAMP '1999-10-29 01:30:00 America/Los_Angeles PDT'
> ```
>
> If you do not add the TZD format element, and the datetime value is
> ambiguous, then Oracle Database returns an error if you have the
> ERROR_ON_OVERLAP_TIME session parameter set to TRUE. If
> ERROR_ON_OVERLAP_TIME is set to FALSE (the default value), then Oracle
> Database interprets the ambiguous datetime as Standard Time.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Before this date, I did not know that CST has different timezone offsets. I have updated my question to be more precise than CST